# npm err! fetch failed in jenkins?

Tags: npm, npm-install

Getting following errors in jenkins.. Any help

`npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/-/cookie-signature-1.0.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 502
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/uid-safe/-/uid-safe-1.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 502`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something is up with the cdn hosting of version 1.0.5. You can force the dependency using cookie-signature to require 1.0.6. Express is dependent on this module and you would be able to resolve the issue like so:

```
"express": {
    "version": "~4.9.0",
     "from": "express@~4.9.0",
        "dependencies": {
           "cookie-signature": {
             "version": "1.0.6",
             "from": "cookie-signature@1.0.6"
        }
    }
},
```